# error installing turtle_teleop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,i am trying to install the turtle_teleop.
I tried running the command "rosdep install turtle_teleop" and got the following    error.what should I do?

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource turtle_teleop
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39410/error-installing-turtle_teleop/) by [hcx31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2896/hcx31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I have found the problem. The package is named "turtlebot_teleop", not "turtle_teleop".

```
allenh1@muri-pc7:~$ rospack find turtle_teleop
[rospack] Error: stack/package turtle_teleop not found
allenh1@muri-pc7:~$ rospack find turtlebot_teleop
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_teleop
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I installed ROS with the package manager. If you did otherwise, then this answer may not be correct; however, I imagine the package names are static on most platforms. Let me know if this doesn't work!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0